# can't get rid of fancybox.gif "Add expires headers" via htaccess?

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I was able to improve my gtmetrix rating a lot by adjusting the according widgets expirations, but I can't get rid of the last few, among them fancybox.gif (and the ones below)

https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js
...ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js
...static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-163991.js?sv=5
...s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/goal.min.js
.../www.yafsparkle.com/skin/frontend/blacknwhite/default/images/fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif
...verify.authorize.net/anetseal/images/secure90x72.gif*

my htaccess looks like this, so the gif is included. Any ideas how I get rid of the remaining ones?

```
-- EXPIRES CACHING --
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote files such as anything **NOT** on your domain yafsparkle.com you won't be able to control the HTTP Headers as they are coming from a 3rd party resource, such as the authorize.net verisign seal, mailchimp coming from an AWS server, etc.

The fancybox_loading.gif however may not be catching the conditioning for the `<filesMatch>` directive because it's coming through via an AJAX request:

- https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js#L974

This is only a theory mind you and it appears the contents of the file referenced is base64 encoded as well, however the apache directive should be based off the filename itself and not the contents.

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Related on a means to cache the loading in fancybox:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620815/cache-content-loaded-via-ajax-in-fancybox

You may also look into `mod_pagespeed` module for Apache it offers a lot of features to help with lots of frontend optimization practices from Google themselves. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

Comment: NP, and welcome to Magento StackExchange! :D

Comment: thx a lot, I appreciate it! so much to learn ;) great to have a community for help!!